# never ending database configuration in 'joomla' installation and can't access phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, xampp, localhost

Im trying to learn developing a simple website using Joomla 3.4.4. I Installed Xampp and joomla. I changed the ports in 'apache' and 'mySQL' from Xampp Control panel. (changing the port httpd.conf file to 8080, port in httpd-ssl.conf file to 4433 and respective one in mySQL to 33066). I can access localhost:8080 and view the home page. But when installing the the joomla on xampp server (after extracting the joomla files to htdocs folder) the first installation page is perfectly loaded and information is asked about the site. When the But in 'database configuration' phase's progress bar never ends. I can't go beyond that. Information provided in database configuration phase is as follow:

- database type: MySQL
- Host Name : localhost:8080
- User Name : root
- password : password
- Database Name : joomla17
- Table Prefix : jj_

There's another problem that was arisen with this installation. Even though I can access localhost:8080 page, I can access phpMyAdmin. It says these errors:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> Cannot connect: invalid settings.
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Please Help me with these issues.

Comment: You are using the apache port as port for the hostname. Use the SQL port (33066)

Comment: @Morten Can you explain that little bit more? Thank you in advance

Comment: You are trying to connect to the database server, which you have changed the default ports (3306) to 33066. The hostname you have typed is to reach the apache server and not the mysqlserver, that's where your progress fails. So it should work by changing 8080 to 33066. If there is a specific field asking which port you want, add the port there instead on the hostname, @Buddhishan-manamperi